# Empty row below last row of data in gridview after binding from XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, vb.net

I am trying to bind XML data into a gridview, after clicking the 'ButtonSaveToDataBase' button, the method will begin to read data from my gridview and load it into an array of my serializable class type and after that serialize it and finally store it into a XML type field in my SQL. The problem is When I call BindData() at the end of the serialization, it reads the XML from my database and successfully binded it but my gridview displays an empty row below my datas like this:

```
Edit-Update     VouCode  Quantity       Delete
Edit               1        3           Delete
Edit                                    Delete
```

Could someone please advice where went wrong, is it the serialization part? Thanks.

```
   Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click    

 'This method will add a new row of data into my gridview but not save it yet.

    Dim newTable As New DataTable("NewTable")
                        newTable.Columns.Add("VouCode")
                        newTable.Columns.Add("QTY")
                        Dim dr2 As DataRow = newTable.NewRow

                        dr2("VouCode") = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex
                        dr2("QTY") = TextBox1.Text
                        newTable.Rows.Add(dr2)
                        ds.Tables.Add(newTable)
                        Me.GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
                        ViewState("VoucherRewardsSet") = ds
                        con.Close() 

    End Sub

Protected Sub ButtonSaveToDataBase_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSaveToDatabase.Click

        Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = Nothing
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Test").ConnectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Campaign_InsertNew", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim cv(GridView1.Rows.Count) As CampaignVoucher 'create an array of gv row size

        Dim vc As String = String.Empty
        Dim qt As Integer

        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1 'loop through gv and load data into array
            vc = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
            qt = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text
            cv(i) = New CampaignVoucher(vc, qt)
        Next


            ' -----------------Serialization ------------------  

            Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(cv.[GetType]())
            Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8)

            serializer.Serialize(writer, cv)

            'get the stream from the writer
            memoryStream = TryCast(writer.BaseStream, MemoryStream)

            'apply encoding to the stream 
            Dim enc As New UTF8Encoding
            Dim xml As String = enc.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()).Trim()

            ' -------------------------------------------        

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@voucherXML", SqlDbType.Text).Value = xml

            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            con.Close()

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1
            BindData()

            TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub

   Private Sub BindData()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Test").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmdSelect As New SqlCommand("Select VoucherXML from RewardVouchers", con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet("VoucherRewardsSet")
        con.Open()
        Using reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
            cmdSelect.Connection = con
            reader.Read()
            If (reader.HasRows) Then
                Dim xml As String = reader.GetString(0)
                'Dim ds As New DataSet()
                ds.ReadXml(New StringReader(xml))
                Dim dtableForGVBinding As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
                Me.GridView1.DataMember = "CampaignVoucher"
                Me.GridView1.DataSource = dtableForGVBinding
                Me.GridView1.DataBind()
            End If
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

**XML copied from my SQL field:**

```
<ArrayOfCampaignVoucher xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<CampaignVoucher VouCode="1" Qty="34" />
<CampaignVoucher xsi:nil="true" />
</ArrayOfCampaignVoucher>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an extra element in your array.

```
Dim cv(GridView1.Rows.Count) As CampaignVoucher 'create an array of gv row size
```

Should be

```
Dim cv(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1) As CampaignVoucher 'create an array of gv row size
```